# Stack Overflow Careers/ Experience Section Checkbox

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

When I edit my CV at Stackoverflow Careers at Experience/Display Options

the Checkbox id="SuppressHeader" is shown not correct.

[image]

System:
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0

Comment: I was able to reproduce in Firefox 24. I'll have someone fix it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This bug has been fixed, thank you for your report !